# Mysqli select query shows invalid results for the query with time intervals

Tags: php, date, mysqli

My table looks like this ->

[image: tabble]

The type of tables with time - time

I use a query like this

```
$stmts = Work::$sql->prepare('SELECT
                                *
                                 FROM `pokemons_location`
                                 WHERE
                                 `location_id` = ? AND
                                 `chance` >= ? AND
                                 (
                                 (`timezone` = ? AND `timezone_b` = ?)
                                   OR
                                 (CAST(? AS time) BETWEEN timezone AND timezone_b)
                                    OR (NOT CAST(? AS time) BETWEEN timezone_b 
                                 AND timezone AND timezone > timezone_b)
                                 )

                                    ORDER BY `chance` DESC
                                    LIMIT ?
                                    ');
            $zero = "00:00:00";
            $chance = mt_rand(1, 100);
            $timezone = date('H:i:s');        
           $chance_limit = random_int(5, 15);

            $stmts->bind_param("iisssss", $location_id, $chance, $zero,$zero, $timezone, $timezone, $chance_limit);
            $stmts->execute();
            $select = $stmts->get_result();
```

There was such a problem that the request began to give me incorrect strings, on another site this question is used for a long time and there are no problems with it.

As a result, after the while loop I get the array I need, with the wrong values

```
500|164|19|261|331|331
```

where 164 and 500 - should occur only in the time interval from 23:55:00 to 04:00:00. A copy of the entry with the number 164 -

[image: row]

var_dump variable with date() at the moment of query execution - string(8) "23:08:24"

As well as the time on the server, and mysqli curtime indicates the correct time zone. ntpdate shows a lag of 0.001042 sec.

UPD:
Noticed that it only displays incorrect results in the first 15-20 minutes from the beginning of each hour, which confuses me even more.

UPD 2:
It is noticed that when querying directly into mysqli, the query is displayed correctly. When querying from under php - it gives wrong answers.

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference but `x not between y and z` is a little easier to read than `not x between y and z`

Comment: @Barmar I changed the query as you indicated, but at this point I can't check if this solved my problem, because the error appears in the first 10-20 minutes from the beginning of each hour and then disappears afterwards.

Comment: Can you reproduce this at sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: @Barmar http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/499522a/1/0

Comment: Your fiddle is only returning the rows where ```(`timezone` = "00:00:00" AND `timezone_b` = "00:00:00")``` is true.

Comment: @Barmar Changed the time in the query, for which the $timezone variable is responsible in the code http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/499522a/7/0 . My script returns all lines that do not have the time set (i.e. 00:00:00), as well as lines if the current time is between x y

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do. It's not reproducing the problem.

Comment: @Barmar I apologize that I forgot to specify in the thread that when you run the query directly in php and when you run it from under mysqli - in mysqli the answer is correct, as it should be, in php - no. Accordingly, with the same query parameters.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction you're making. `mysqli` is the library you use to run the query from PHP.

Comment: @Barmar I don't understand it either, and neither do you. But in reality I do. in the code, the only thing that could cause an error in the query and give the wrong time is the $timezone variable. But in var_dump both result and value of this variable were written in the query and they were correct, exactly the same as in sqlfidle

Comment: This seems like an issue with time difference between PHP and MySQL. But you're formatting the time string in PHP, and MySQL should just work with that string, and time skew shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Barmar That's what I thought, so I checked the time zones everywhere to make sure that was not the case. I'll try to figure out the request logging when the problem resumes. The problem here could only be an error in the $timezone variable or reading it, if the request was made correctly. I don't know. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: I think the problem lies with the betweens. If I have a list of 1 to 50. Selecting 10 and 20 will give me the same list as 20 and 10.  So on you or not. That is selecting all the other records.

Comment: If there were a problem with `BETWEEN` then we should be able to reproduce it at sqlfiddle or when running the query by hand in the `mysql` command line tool.

Comment: Server support advised to disable caching and opcache. Although my other server with the same settings and the same code does not give an error in the same request =) I'll probably change the logic and tables, and check the time already in the code. The table is not that big, I don't think it will noticeably slow anything down.